# Laravel 5.4: Method not allowed for post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm starting creating an API, testing the routes. Here is my routes/api.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'ApiController@index');
Route::post('/foo', 'ApiController@store');
```

And this is my ApiController.php

```
public function index()
{
   return 'Hello, API';
}

public function store()
{
    return 'API POST';
}
```

On Postman, GET method works. But POST return 405 code.

There is no restriction on my Http/Kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
       ...
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

[image]

Comment: Add screenshot of your post request in Postman

Comment: @Thamilan added the screenshot.

Comment: Maybe are you trying to access to the /foo route without post method ?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Are you use `Route::group` because your url are api/foo

Comment: try using : `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept:application/json` with your postman in Headers tab

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd if api routes is added to routes/api.php file, Laravel automatically add 'api' group. The GET route is working.

Comment: @yoeunes I add this to Header but the result is the same.

Comment: how about other urls ?
every post route you add has this problem ?

Comment: @MasoudHaghbin yes, it seems like every Post route has this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `/api/foo` but not `/api/foo/`. Because if you are using Apache and check in access log you will get moved permanently to `GET /api/foo`.

Comment: Stupid mistake. Thanks!